# Iterate through point feature class and apply tool to specific groups of features

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I am new to Python/ArcPy.

Currently I am trying to iterate through a point feature class and apply the tool "arcpy.AggregatePoints_cartography" to the group of point features for every new time step and as well if the ID (field "ID" not "OBJECTID" changes. The attribute table looks like this:

[image: Attribute table]

The field "Monat" includes values up to 12. And the ID-field varies between the values 1 and 2.

I tried to use a search cursor in combination with a counter "LaufID", but the Output Feature class only contains two polygons, but there should be 24 polygons. Please help?

```py
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:/Users/.../Geodatabase.mdb"
laufID = -1

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Schatten", ["ID","Tag","Monat"]) as cursorP:
    for pnt in cursorP:
        ID = pnt[0]
        day = pnt[1]
        mon = pnt[2]

        if laufID == -1:
            laufID = ID

        if laufID != ID:
            arcpy.AggregatePoints_cartography("Schatten", "Schatten_Aggr", "100 meters")
```

Comment: Is it ok with unique combinations of ID, Tag, Monat or do you want as you say whenever any of them changes?

Comment: Unique combinations are ok.

Comment: No it's ArcMap 10.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want the aggregated polygons in separate feature classes, this code, will make it. See the last line to optionally merge all polygons in one feature class:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:/Users/.../Geodatabase.mdb"

arcpy.Statistics_analysis("Schatten", "Combi", "OBJECTID COUNT", "ID; Tag; Monat")

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Combi", ["ID, Tag, Monat"]) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Schatten", "lyr", """ID = {} AND Tag = {} AND Monat = {}""".format(row[0], row[1], row[2]))
        arcpy.AggregatePoints_cartography("lyr", """Aggr_{}_{}_{}""".format(row[0], row[1], row[2]), "100 meters")

# add this line if you want to merge all polygons in one single feature class:
arcpy.Merge_management(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Aggr_*"), "All_polygons")
```

Comment: The x[0], x[1]... in lines 11/12 are labled with warnings so that a syntax error (invalid syntax) occurs

Comment: The first part of the Code is working somehow (I think there's a bracket missing in line 11 after x[2],) , but the Loop seems not to work correct, because in the geodatabase only one result Feature class is found.

Comment: I can't figure it out, but the loop still somehow creates only one polygon.

Comment: This is the ouput for the print statement: 1 1 1

Comment: The zip is not creating all possible combinations of ID, Tag and Monat?

Comment: Indeed. Here is another code (less elegant but should work better)

Comment: I prefer this newer version, less lines of code and easier to read.

Comment: map93 thanks for your patience! @Hornbydd me too, but I like to experiment with Python functions...

Answer (score 2):

Whilst @map93 was seeking a python solution, this can be done very simply in model builder, the model is nothing more than below:

[image: Model]

Note I add the 3 fields to the *Group By* parameter of the iterator and this gives the unique combinations. If you want to merge them into a single dataset feed the output of Aggregate points into a collects tool and expose that from a sub-model to a master model with a single merge tool.

As iterators do not export to python, you could create this model and call it from your script by importing the toolbox and calling it.